# Using a laravel-view in a api-call to mandril

Tags: php, api, laravel, mandrill

Ok, so I'm setting up a call to send an email using the mandrill-wrapper from packagist (rather than the build in mandrill-driver) since I want to use merge-vars.

So I set up my view and filled it. It renders correctly, all variables are set up and all is good (I test this by returning the view and see it's good).

next I set up $message, merge_vars- and to-array to send to my mandrill-object.

For $message["html"] I simply put

```
$message = array(
        'html' => View::make(
             'emails.wishlist.share',
             array(
               'name'=>Auth::user()->fName, 
               'list'=>$list));
...
);
```

if I just return the view, I can see it renders correctly, but when I actually make the api-call, I can see in the api-log, that the html-field is empty.

Is this because View::make() actually returns an object? And how to I get the raw html in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View::make()` and `view()` return a view object. Call `render` to get the raw HTML string:

```php
$message = [
    'html' => view('emails.wishlist.share', [
        'name' => auth()->user()->fName, 
        'list' => $list,
    ])->render(),
];
```

Comment: I had to use View::make()->render, but other than that, it worked flawlessly :) Thanks!

Comment: @Atheist - isn't that what I've shown you here? What didn't work here and what did you have to change it to? `View::make()` and `view()` are both exactly the same.

Comment: I get an exception: 
Call to undefined function view(), but if I call View::make I have no problems...

Comment: @Atheist - are you by any chance stuck on laravel 4.2? Time to upgrade.

Comment: That would be it :)
I want to get my app up and running - I've already passed my personal deadline with over 14 days...